# New York City- Tenant Rights

Tags: landlord, new-york-state, tenant, new-york-city, fair-housing-acts

I have a question regarding tenant's rights under a leased property; I can't seem to find the answer anywhere online.

***What are the obligations of a tenant in a 1yr lease to provide notice of vacating the premises by the end of the lease, if there is no language in the lease describing such a notice? In other words, is there New York City or New York State law that requires a minimum notice to be given to the landlord if the lease is not to be renewed?***

Any help is greatly appreciated! I have tried to look in Article 7 under real property laws (Landlord and Tenant laws) but cannot find any relevant language!

Answer (score 1):

> What are the obligations of a tenant in a 1yr lease to provide notice of vacating the premises by the end of the lease, if there is no language in the lease describing such a notice?

Apparently there is none as long as the tenant leaves the property by the expiration date. The closest statutory provision in this regard is [section 232-C of article 7](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/RPP/232-C), which addresses leases of "*term longer than one month*". That statute does not require the tenant to give notice.

In the more difficult scenario of a tenant requesting to be released from a lease, [section 226-B](https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/RPP/226-B) mentions a 30-day period of forced release if the landlord *unreasonably* withholds consent. However, a tenant's decision not to renew a lease does not need landlord's consent, whence the guidance from section 226-B seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the lease is for [a rent-stabilized apartment](https://hcr.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2020/11/fact-sheet-04-06-2019.pdf), the landlord must deliver a [renewal form](https://hcr.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2020/11/rtp-8-06-2020.pdf) which offers renewal (between 90 and 150 days before the end of the lease, depending). The tenant has 60 days from receipt of the offer to select 1 year, 2 year, or no renewal and return the form to the landlord. The defines when the tenant must accept or reject the offer.

In case the unit is a market-rate apartment, according to [this source](https://www.metcouncilonhousing.org/help-answers/renewing-your-lease-in-an-unregulated-market-rate-apartment/), it primarily depends on what the offer or lease says. Then,

> If neither the offer nor the lease agreement specify the duration of
> the offer, then principles of contract law govern.
>
> “An offer that is not irrevocable does not stay open indefinitely.
> Although an offer does not specify the time by which acceptance must
> be made, the offer is deemed to be open and available to be accepted
> for a reasonable time unless sooner revoked. If such reasonable time
> has passed, the offer is deemed to have lapsed and cannot be
> accepted.” (New York Practice Series – New York Contract Law § 2:8).

If you do not accept the offer, you have no further legal obligation other than to be gone at the end of the lease period.